# iPhone - NSPredicate (adding more filters)

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have this predicate

```
NSPredicate *myPredicate =
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date == %@) && (enabled == %@)", date, isEnabled];
```

At some point, if a boolean test is valid, I would like to add a third filter to this predicate, something like

```
if (testValid) {
    // use some magic to add a third option here
    // the third option is "&& (paid == %@")
    // and the condition is given by isPaid
    // the idea is to append a third condition on myPredicate, making it like
    // myPredicate =
    //   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date == %@) && (enabled == %@) && (paid == %@)", date, isEnabled, isPaid];
}
```

I suppose I can create a NSMutableString for the format and append the third part if necessary, but I suspect there's a way to do it using NSPredicate in a more elegant way.

How do I do that? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `NSCompoundPredicate` which lets you construct an instance of `NSPredicate` from one or more subpredicates:

```
NSArray *subpreds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:existingPredicate, [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:...], nil];
NSPredicate *finished = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpreds];
```